Can you use numerical approximation for finding equilibrium?
I'm working on my thesis on prey-predator system. I have 3 species here, 1 prey and 1 predator with 1 species having a mutualism with the prey and protecting the prey from predators. Here is the system :
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=r_1x(1-\frac{x}{\gamma})-\frac{xz}{1+\alpha N+x}+\theta_1xy$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=r_2y(1-\frac{y}{\gamma})+\theta_2xy-\Delta_1yz$$
$$\frac{dz}{dt}=\frac{Bz(x+N)}{1+\alpha N+x}-\Delta_2yz-Mz$$
Finding equilibria without the presence of predator is pretty easy. So far 2 equilibrium $E_0=(0,0,0)$ and $E_1=(x_1^*,y_1^*,0)$ has been found. The problem is for the third equilibria where all species live together. It is really hard to find the closed form solutions of the third equilibria.  So, I stop here at these equations by $f_i(x,y,z)=0$ we get :
$$r_1x(1-\frac{x}{\gamma})-\frac{xz}{1+\alpha N+x}+\theta_1xy=0$$
$$\frac{B(x+N)}{1+\alpha N+x}-\Delta_2y-M=0$$
$$\frac{r_2}{\Delta_1}(1-\frac{y}{\gamma})+\frac{\theta_2}{\Delta_1}x=z$$
From here I don't know how to proceed to analyze the stability of the third equilibrium since how can you input the equation to the jacobian matrix of the system. How shall I approach on this problem? Can I do Newton-Raphson or any numerical approximation in my problem here? I wish I could somehow make it shorter.
From above, i try to make $x$ as a parameter and solving for $y$ and $z$ that gives me polynomial of $x$ in degree of 3. I tried using software Mathematica to work on the solution of this system. Mathematica give me 3 non-trivial equilibrium (this is because the polynomial in 3rd degree) which is a very large output. I couldn't find online how to analyze the stability of a non linear system like this. Any suggestions are very much appreciated. Thank you.
$r_i$ is the rate of growth species-i. $\gamma$ is the system capacity that can hold how much of the species. $alpha$ is the additional food quality. $N$ is the quantity of the additional food. $B$ is maximum growth of predator. $\theta_i$ is the amount of profit from mutualism to the species. $\Delta_i$ is the rate of death because interaction of predator and species 2. And $M$ is the rate of death of predator.
Edit : all symbols are all constant parameters, the only variables are $x$, $y$, and $z$
Edit 2 : Adding additional info on the parameters.

Are $B, \alpha, \Delta_2, M$ constants? Maybe it would help to define all constants in the problem statement.

@Moo yes they are all constants, the only variable is $x,y$, and $z$

You already found $z$ in the 3rd equation. You can single out $y$ from the 2nd equation. Putting everything together in the 1st equation you can obtain $x$ in terms of constants.

@obareey yes, but it gives more question to me. I already did that as i said, if i try to take $y$ and $z$ depends on x, there will be a polynomial function $f(x)$ with degree of 3. This is not an easy task as there are so many parameters. Furthermore, if we leave $f(x)$ as it is, we arrive at my question above, can we input this polynomial $f(x)$, $y(x,t)$, and $z(x,t)$ into the jacobian matrix? I think this is not possible and there need to be another approach on how to tackle this problem

You don't need to input the polynomial into the Jacobian. Solving the polynomial will give you the fixed points, which are constant values. When calculating the Jacobian around a fixed point, you enter the value of the selected fixed point into the Jacobian for linearization. Jacobian matrix is calculated by the partial derivatives of $x,y,z$, which should be straightforward.

@obareey the problem is the root of the polynominal are humongous. I have tried to find it with software like Mathematica and Maplesoft. Couldn't even write all that down on paper

Hint.
To use criteria as Routh-Hurwitz the system should be linearized. Let the nonlinear system be represented as
$$
\dot x = f(x,\theta)
$$
at $x_0$ we have the linear approximation
$$
\dot x = f(x_0,\theta)+\nabla_x f(x_0,\theta)(x-x_0) = A(x_0,\theta)x+b(x_0,\theta)
$$
applying the Laplace transform with null initial conditions we get
$$
X(s) = (I s - A(x_0,\theta))^{-1}\frac{b(x_0,\theta)}{s}
$$
and the stability is determined by the roots of
$$
\det(I s - A(x_0,\theta))=0
$$
which is a third order polynomial. Applying now the Routh-Hurwitz criterion for instance, for stable roots, we will obtain a set of conditions $g_i(x_0,\theta) \ge 0$ so the problem now is to determine sets of $\{x_0,\theta\}$ which obey those conditions. This last step can be done with the help of an optimization solver.
